# set null value in a foreign key column?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, constraints, relationship

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CityMaster](
    [CityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [BranchId] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__CityM__Branc__74444068]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ExternalBranchId] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CityMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [City] ASC,
    [BranchId] ASC
),
 CONSTRAINT [uk_citymaster_cityid_branchid] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CityID] ASC,
    [BranchId] ASC
)
)
```

and another table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerMaster](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerCode] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CustomerAddress] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CustomerPhone] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CustomerEmailId] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CustomerPriority] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_CustomerMaster_CustomerPriority]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CustomerRegisterDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CustomerIsActive] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_CustomerMaster_CustomerIsActive]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [BranchId] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__CustomerM__Branc__67DE6983]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CityId] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_CustomerMaster_CityId]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerCode] ASC,
    [BranchId] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerMaster]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_cdCityId_CityId] FOREIGN KEY([CityId], [BranchId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CityMaster] ([CityID], [BranchId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerMaster] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_cdCityId_CityId]
```

As you can see, there is a foreign key on `CityId, BranchId`. The problem I am having is, if a user doesn't enters his city (he can opt not to, this field not mandatory, then the `CityId` would be blank and when I try to insert this value in the `CustomerMaster` table, I get this error saying

**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_cdCityId_CityId". The conflict occurred in database "TestDatabase", table "dbo.CityMaster".
The statement has been terminated.**

So, I wanna know a way to circumvent this. I know if a unique or a primary key column is referenced as a foreign key, it can not be null. But, what about the times, when I've set 
`on delete set null`? In that case, if that row is deleted from `CityMaster` it would be set to `null` in `CustomerMaster` (I mean all its references). so, if that's possible why and how can I set the value in this foreign key `null` manually?
And if that's not possible by any means, what's the best way to circumvent the situation I described?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If `CityId` is set to `NULL`, then the foreign key constraint will not be checked, and all will be good.

On the other hand, if `CityId` is 0 (say, because you've specified `DEFAULT ((0))` on it...), and there's no matching row in `CityMaster` for `0,BranchId`, then this will indeed cause the constraint check to fail.

A foreign key constraint on a composite key is only checked if *all* of the columns involved are non-`NULL`.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever:
So, I should remove this `default (0)` clause?

Comment: @Razort4x - I would say so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Change in `insert query @`

```
[CityId] [int] DEFAULT NULL
```

This will allow you to store `Null` value as you declared it as default.