# "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" when insert is NULL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this problem: I have this table which has 5 columns: `ID, Usuario_IdUsuario, Artista_IdArtista, Disco_IdDisco, Lista_IdLista`. The last 4 are foreign keys, and the last 2 allow nulls, because at the time of their creation, the tables they are referencing are empty. So I insert `Usuario_IdUsuario` and `Artsita_IdArtista` and I get the following message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Sigue_Lista". The conflict occurred in database "Tarea2", table "dbo.Lista", column 'IdLista'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

But that table is empty, and not inserting anything there, since it allows nulls. I already checked, it does not have a default value.

Note: This might be considered as "Duplicate" but the answers given in previous questions don't work for me and I can't comment to ask what happens if that doesn't work (default value thing).

The insert code where the problem appears:

```
string insertQuery2 = "insert into Sigue (Usuario_IdUsuario, Artista_IdArtista) values (@usu, @Artista);"; //if I delete the ; inside the "", then it doesn't show any error messages, but it doesn't isert anything into the table either. 
SqlCommand sig = new SqlCommand(insertQuery2, conn);

sig.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usu", idusu); //UserId taken from user table
sig.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artista", idar); //ArtistId taken from artist table.

sig.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm working with C# on Visual Studio 2012 and also using SQL Server 2012 with Management Studio)

```
USE [Tarea2] 
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Sigue]    Script Date: 02-11-2014 20:32:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sigue](
    [IdSigue] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Usuario_IdUsuario] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Artista_IdArtista] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Disco_IdDisco] [int] NULL,
    [Lista_IdLista] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sigue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdSigue] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Sigue_Disco_IdDisco]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR     [Disco_IdDisco]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Sigue_Lista_IdLista]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR     [Lista_IdLista]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Artista] FOREIGN     KEY([Artista_IdArtista])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Artista] ([IdArtista])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Artista]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Disco] FOREIGN     KEY([Disco_IdDisco])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Disco] ([IdDisco])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Disco]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Lista] FOREIGN     KEY([Lista_IdLista])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Lista] ([IdLista])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Lista]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_UserData] FOREIGN     KEY([Usuario_IdUsuario])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserData] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_UserData]
GO
```

Comment: `null` isn't a valid foreign key - what isn't clear about the error message?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Where does the error message say anything about `null`?

Comment: The title says the value is null. The error message indicates the value violates the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Well the null in the title is outside the citation. It's not part of the error message, so it is added by OP, assuming that this causes the problem.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot null is treated as valid in a FK anyway.

Comment: The problem is that he's trying to insert a value into a field with a foreign key constraint, and that the value doesn't exist in the table with the relationship. The OP stated that the value that he's trying to insert is `null`. Whether value he's trying to insert is `"A"`, `"George Washington"`, `"foo"`, `4.123441` or `null` is irrelevant, the point is that the value doesn't exist, which is what the error message indicates.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot it's nothing to do with the null columns. Must be one of the others. You can insert null into a FK column and there is no requirement that a null exists on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a099/1 and see for yourself: Inserting `NULL` into a foreign key column is not a problem!

Comment: Any triggers on the table? Also can you script out the full create table including foreign keys?

Comment: I see you added the CREATE TABLE statement. However we can't see the foreign key definition in this.

Comment: You've messed up the FK declarations. They should be using different columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]  
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Lista] FOREIGN KEY([IdSigue])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Lista] ([IdLista])
```

Should be

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]  
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Lista] FOREIGN KEY(Lista_IdLista)
REFERENCES [dbo].[Lista] ([IdLista])
```

You are validating the wrong column. Currently the behaviour is that it will validate the value in `IdSigue` appears in `[dbo].[Lista]`. This isn't the correct semantics.

The same error appears in most of your other FK definitions too.

Comment: I didn't notice that. I fixed it and now, it doesn't show any error messages, but nothing is inserted into the table either.

Comment: @JavierGonzález possibly  it is in a transaction that you aren't comitting then.

Comment: I don't know what happened, restarted my computer and now my code works :D Thank you thank you thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the two columns to `NULL` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sigue (Usuario_IdUsuario, Artista_IdArtista, Disco_IdDisco, Lista_IdLista) VALUES (@usu, @Artista, NULL, NULL);
```

According to the following links, this should work:
[set null value in a foreign key column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495297/set-null-value-in-a-foreign-key-column)
[Can table columns with a foreign key be null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null)

Since you mentioned, that the column does NOT have a default value set, you can also try to set the default value to `NULL` instead.

You can see in this little [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a099/1), that inserting `NULL` into foreign keys is not a problem at all.

**After question was edited:**
Now, that you provide the info on how you created the foreign keys: You are creating all four foreign keys on the same column `IdSigue`.

The ALTER TABLE statements should be changed from:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]
  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Artista]
  FOREIGN KEY([IdSigue]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Artista] ([IdArtista])
```

to:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sigue]
  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Sigue_Artista]
  FOREIGN KEY([Artista_IdArtista]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Artista] ([IdArtista])
```

The difference is in the `()` after `FOREIGN KEY`.

Do this for the other three foreign key definitions as well.

Last but not least a couple of links on the topic:
[How do I create a foreign key in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server)
http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_Create_foreign_key_contraints.php

Comment: Could you please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `Sigue` in your question?
Maybe try something like this to create it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table

Comment: Noob Question: How do I post the code here keeping the format of the code?

Comment: Too much code for a comment. Edit your question and put it in there!

Comment: Why would you ever want null in a foreign key column though? What's the purpose of the foreign key then.

Comment: The purpose of the foreign key is to make sure, that if the column is set to something NOT NULL, this value has to be pointing to a row in another table. It's the same reasoning for a foreign key, without allowing NULL...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925203/any-example-of-a-necessary-nullable-foreign-key for examples!

Comment: Excellent link @wolfgangwalther. I've just never encountered an example like that before.